# How to retrieve the value of selected id from a table or "list"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP. I need some help regarding getting the value from a selected `id`. I have a list of data inserted into my database and also selected all of the data from the database. Meaning the value of all data are display on a page.

What I want is when I **select "id=1"** from the table or list it will direct it to a page where it display the value of "id=1" same as "id=2" and onward. It is like a link to another page but I won't create a page for each id but a template that get the value of selected id number from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional and simplest approach is:

Make your "list" a database table. Add a new row to that table when you want to add a product.

Put the value of the PRIMARY KEY column in the URL, usually in a query string.

```
http://example.com/products.php?product_id=123
```

Read that value from `$_GET` and use it it in a database query to get the information needed to generate the page.

Output the page with that data in it.

Prettier URLs can be achieved with URL rewriting. You might want to look at MVC frameworks which implement routing and convenient methods to define nicer URIs.